# MySQL CLI same query different results between the interactive and non interactive mode

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if I am running into a weird bug or some undocumented problem. This is also really hard to Google as the keywords to describe this are vague.

As you can see in the output below, if I use the interactive MySQL CLI client and manually select my database and put in the query I get a result of `397`, if I use the non interactive mode with `-e` with the EXACT same query I get a count of 0.

Why is this?

```
Database changed
MySQL [mydatabase]> SELECT count(*) FROM mydatabase.DomainVersions AS
dv LEFT JOIN domains AS d ON dv.DomainId = d.DomainId WHERE
dv.TemplateId LIKE 'companyDC-Vpc_2021-05%' AND (d.DomainMode =
'"VPC"' OR d.DomainMode = '"CONNECT"') AND NOT DomainState =
'"Deleted"' AND NOT DomainState = '"Deleting"' AND NOT DomainState =
'"Failed"';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      397 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)

MySQL [mydatabase]> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
[/home/myself]
    myself@devbox $ mysql -u $mysqlUsername --password=$mysqlPasswd -h
$mysqlHostname -e "use mydatabase; SELECT count(*) FROM
mydatabase.DomainVersions AS dv LEFT JOIN mydatabase.domains AS d ON
dv.DomainId = d.DomainId WHERE dv.TemplateId LIKE
'companyDC-Vpc_2021-05%' AND (d.DomainMode = '"VPC"' OR d.DomainMode
= '"CONNECT"') AND NOT DomainState = '"Deleted"' AND NOT DomainState
= '"Deleting"' AND NOT DomainState = '"Failed"';"
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

Comment: It is very strange that you are storing string with a double quotes delimiter.  I wonder if that is related to the discrepancy.

Comment: Yeah, that was an unfortunate mistake from long ago that cannot be easily undone.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you were right! I put escapes around the double quotes and I got the same count, thank you so much. Feel free to post an answer of that and I'll accept it for you.